# Checking if an object is empty

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
function check Files()
{
    if (jQuery.isEmptyObject($('#fileupload').files) == true){
        changeStage1Class();
    }
}
```

The code is checking if something is uploaded. When it's empty it returns "true". But even when there is a file uploaded it still returns "true". Is the code not working correctly?

Comment: try === instead of == .

Comment: The problem is back again. ?

Answer (score 1):

`$('#fileupload')` gives you jQuery object and not the direct html element, you need to invoke `get()` on it:

```
$('#fileupload').get(0).files
```

Also you cannot have spaces between names:

```
function check Files() {
             ^^
}
```

`$('#fileupload').get(0).files.length`  gives the file count > 0, if file was chosen

Try this:

```
if ($('#fileupload').get(0).files.length){
   changeStage1Class();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry that was a mistake of copying the code here by my part.

I did what you said and it works now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just changed the (0) to (1) and it works now. Is that a sufficient change?

Comment: I've got fileupload.js 
fileupload-process.js 
etc etc

Comment: Thats strange, do you have multiple `<input type='file' id='fileupload'/>` with same id fileupload ?

Comment: No I don't.
All I want the code to do is return to "stage1" if there are no files left. What it is doing now is if I upload multiple files and delete 1 they all disappear and I go back to "stage1". With your code ".get(1)" I can delete 1 file at a time without going back to "stage1" but even when I delete all of the files and there is nothing left, I am not redirected to "stage1".